# Print Function values inside a table?

Tags: php, function, html-table

How  do I print the value of a function inside a table? I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out, looked it up in Google, watch some Youtube PHP tutorials and still came up with nothing, and there is also an error telling me that $cols, $rows, $rNumber is undefined. The output should look like a half pyramid.

```
<?php
do {
    $rNumber = mt_rand(3, 11);
} while ($rNumber % 2 == 0);

echo '<strong>Looping Statements Exercises</strong>';
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
echo 'This page shows eight (8) figures programatically generated by looping statements. Number of rows are random odd integer between 3 and 11.';
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';


echo '<table border = "1">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td colspan = "4"><center>Size:<strong>', $rNumber, ' x ', $rNumber, '</strong>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td> Figure A';
echo '<td> Figure B';
echo '<td> Figure C';
echo '<td> Figure D';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td> Figure A here';
echo '<td>', figure_b($cols, $rows), '</td>';
echo '<td> Figure C here';
echo '<td> Figure D here';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td> Figure E';
echo '<td> Figure F';
echo '<td> Figure G';
echo '<td> Figure H';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td> Figure E here';
echo '<td> Figure F here';
echo '<td> Figure G here';
echo '<td> Figure H here';
echo '</tr>';


function figure_b($rows, $cols)
{
    if ($rNumber == 5) {
        for ($rows = 0; $rows <= 5; $rows++) {
            for ($cols = 0; $cols <= 5; $cols++) {

                return $cols;
            }
            return $rows;
        }
    }
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: figure_b($cols, $rows) where is that variables ?

Comment: It's not causing the error, but maybe ou should close <td> tags...

Answer (score 0):

Your function:

```
function figure_b($rows, $cols)
{
if($rNumber == 5)
{
for($rows = 0; $rows<=5; $rows++)
{
for ($cols = 0; $cols<=5; $cols++)
{

return $cols;
}
return $rows;
}
}
}
```

is completely wrong.

It should be rather:

```
function figure_b($rNumber)
{
    if ($rNumber == 5) {
        for ($rows = 0; $rows <= 5; $rows++) {
            for ($cols = 0; $cols <= 5; $cols++) {
                echo $cols.' '; 
            }
            echo $rows.'<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to display anything inside your table and use `rNumber` variable (it seems there's no need to pass `$rows` and `$cols` variables here)

However your code is really bad, you should not mix PHP code and HTML code that way. If you need to you should move some part of your code to other file and not use so many `echo` because it also affects your performance.

Answer (score 0):

you can begin by trying to changhe this

```
 $rNumber = mt_rand(3,11);
}while ($rNumber % 2 == 0);
```

to this :

```
    $rNumber = mt_rand(3,11);                               
   while ($rNumber % 2 == 0);
```

and your function to :

```
    function figure_b($rNumber) 
   {
               if($rNumber == 5) 
                 {
                     for($rows = 0; $rows<=5; $rows++) 
                       {
                           for ($cols = 0; $cols<=5; $cols++) 
                                {

                                    echo $cols;
                                 }
                                   echo $rows;
                          }
                  }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

 do{
                                        $rNumber = mt_rand(3,11);
                                        }while ($rNumber % 2 == 0);

                                        echo '<strong>Looping Statements Exercises</strong>';
                                        echo '<br>';
                                        echo '<br>';
                                        echo 'This page shows eight (8) figures programatically generated by looping statements. Number of rows are random odd integer between 3 and 11.';
                                        echo '<br>';
                                        echo '<br>';


                                        echo '<table border = "1">';
                                        echo '<tr>';
                                        echo '<td colspan = "4"><center>Size:<strong>',$rNumber,' x ',$rNumber,'</strong>';
                                        echo '</tr>';
                                        echo '<tr>';
                                        echo '<td> Figure A';
                                        echo '<td> Figure B';
                                        echo '<td> Figure C';
                                        echo '<td> Figure D';
                                        echo '</tr>';
                                        echo '<tr>';
                                        echo '<td> Figure A here';
                                        echo '<td>', figure_b(5, 5,$rNumber),'</td>';
                                        echo '<td> Figure C here';
                                        echo '<td> Figure D here';
                                        echo '</tr>';
                                        echo '<tr>';
                                        echo '<td> Figure E';
                                        echo '<td> Figure F';
                                        echo '<td> Figure G';
                                        echo '<td> Figure H';
                                        echo '</tr>';
                                        echo '<tr>';
                                        echo '<td> Figure E here';
                                        echo '<td> Figure F here';
                                        echo '<td> Figure G here';
                                        echo '<td> Figure H here';
                                        echo '</tr>';


                                        function figure_b($rows, $cols,$rNumber) 
                                        {
                                            if($rNumber == 5) 
                                            {
                                                for($rows = 0; $rows<=5; $rows++) 
                                                {
                                                    for ($cols = 0; $cols<=5; $cols++) 
                                                    {

                                                    return $cols;
                                                    }
                                                return $rows;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        echo '</table>';

?>
```